# Case-insensitive JsonNode in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to deserialize JSON objects and access the fields in a case-insensitive manner.  Example:

```
String s = "{\"FOO\": 123}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(s);
node.get("foo"); // this should return the "FOO" field
```

This needs to be performant, so calling `getFieldNames()` and lowercasing the results is not a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no automated way, but you could do it by creating custom JsonNodeFactory which creates custom ObjectNodes -- and then you can override method(s) used for adding and accessing entries.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is available as of 2.5 (Jan 2015):

**ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES**

> Feature that will allow for more forgiving deserialization of incoming JSON. If enabled, the bean properties will be matched using their lower-case equivalents, meaning that any case-combination (incoming and matching names are canonicalized by lower-casing) should work.
> Note that there is additional performance overhead since incoming property names need to be lower-cased before comparison, for cases where there are upper-case letters. Overhead for names that are already lower-case should be negligible however.

Feature is disabled by default.

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as other's have noted, Jackson's `JsonNode` doesn't offer an internal feature for a case insensitive key lookup.  However, lucky for us, most `JsonNode`'s can be easily converted to a map, and there are a few other `Map` implementations that do in fact offer a case insensitive lookup.  The easiest of these is [Spring's `LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.html), but [Java's `TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) will also work.

All we have to do is convert the JsonNode to the map of choice and do the lookup there.  I've listed a few examples below, and I'm using the below method to create a JsonNode for use with these classes;

```java
public JsonNode createNode()
{
  Map<String, List<String>> table = new HashMap<>();
  table.put("first", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("firstprop1", "firstprop2")));
  table.put("second", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("secondprop1", "secondprop2")));
  table.put("third", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("thirdprop1", "thirdprop2")));

  return new ObjectMapper().valueToTree(table);
}
```

## LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap

If you are using Spring, I recommend using the `LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap`.  You won't need to update your dependencies and it "preserves the original order as well as the original casing of keys, while allowing for contains, get and remove calls with any case of key."

### Example

```java
public JsonNode getCaseInsensitiveKey(JsonNode node, String key)
{
  var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Map<String, Object> testing =
      mapper.convertValue(node, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.class, List.class));
  return mapper.valueToTree(testing.get(key));
}
```

## TreeMap

`TreeMap` is the vanilla java solution.  `TreeMap` takes a custom comparator as a constructor argument.  You can use String bundled comparator `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` to create a case insensitive comparator.

### Example

```java
public JsonNode getCaseInsensitiveKeyFromTreeMap(JsonNode node, String key)
{
  var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  TreeMap<String, Object> testing = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
  testing.putAll(mapper.convertValue(node, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, List.class)));
  return mapper.valueToTree(testing.get(key));
}
```

## Testing

The above methods work for the following tests.

```java
@Test
public void testCaseInsensitivity()
{
  var testNode = createNode();
  var result1 = getCaseInsensitiveKey(testNode, "first");
  var result2 = getCaseInsensitiveKey(testNode, "FiRsT");
  var result3 = getCaseInsensitiveKey(testNode, "FIRST");
  assertEquals(result1, result2);
  assertEquals(result1, result3);
}

@Test
public void testCaseInsensitivityFromTreeMap()
{
  var testNode = createNode();
  var result1 = getCaseInsensitiveKeyFromTreeMap(testNode, "first");
  var result2 = getCaseInsensitiveKeyFromTreeMap(testNode, "FiRsT");
  var result3 = getCaseInsensitiveKeyFromTreeMap(testNode, "FIRST");
  assertEquals(result1, result2);
  assertEquals(result1, result3);
```

## Limitations

Note that the above examples will only work to create a `Map<String, List>`.  This means it will not work with OPs example, which maps an integer, and not a list.  However, we can modify this to dynamically assign the inner class using java generics.

### Example

```java
public <T> JsonNode getCaseInsensitiveKey(JsonNode node, String key, Class<T> clazz)
{
  var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Map<String, T> testing =
      mapper.convertValue(node, mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap.class, clazz));
  return mapper.valueToTree(testing.get(key));
}
```

### Testing

Now, with the above modification, we can test the OPs example and successfully get the correct result.

```java
@Test
public void useOfOpExample() throws JsonProcessingException
{
  String s = "{\"FOO\": 123}";
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(s);
  var fooNode1 = getCaseInsensitiveKey(node, "foo", Integer.class);
  var fooNode2 = getCaseInsensitiveKey(node, "FOO", Integer.class);
  assertEquals(fooNode1, fooNode2);
}
```

We are also able to still use our previous tests, with a slight modification, to also get the same result.

```java
@Test
public void testCaseInsensitivity()
{
  var testNode = createNode();
  var result1 = getCaseInsensitiveKey(testNode, "first", List.class);
  var result2 = getCaseInsensitiveKey(testNode, "FiRsT", List.class);
  var result3 = getCaseInsensitiveKey(testNode, "FIRST", List.class);
  assertEquals(result1, result2);
  assertEquals(result1, result3);
}
```